# how to install ruby-netcdf with ruby 2.2?

Tags: ruby, netcdf

When I try to install the gem ruby-netcdf on Fedora I got the following.
Using ruby 2.2 and rvm (also tried ruby 1.8.7 but narray gem doesn t build properly) 
Any help is welcome, thanks.

```
$ gem install ruby-netcdf

Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-netcdf:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


 /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150128-5543-74d90a.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
extconf.rb:4:in `<main>': uninitialized constant Gem::GemPathSearcher (NameError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@testnetcdf/gems/ruby-netcdf-0.6.6.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@testnetcdf/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.2.0/ruby-netcdf-0.6.6.1/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 0):

> By default, RubyNetCDF tries to use the NetCDF library (libncdap)

from http://www.gfd-dennou.org/arch/ruby/products/ruby-netcdf/#installation

So my guess is you need to install the libncdap package or the libncdap-dev package.